# Revoke Dropbox access in Java/Android SDK

Tags: android, dropbox-api, access-token

I can get access token from Dropbox, using this code :

```
Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.DROPBOX_APP_KEY));
```

But how can I revoke access to Dropbox from Java/Android SDK?

Comment: Do you know how to do this with any other language? It might be portable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DbxUserAuthRequests tokenRevoke`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/auth/DbxUserAuthRequests.html#tokenRevoke--) method to revoke the access token. That will cause any further API calls with that token to fail.

You can then delete the token from your app's storage.